# Calling a Controller from another controller in laravel 4 not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, controller, url-routing

I have a controller which saves my form data and after saving that data i am trying to redirect my page to another form.But Redirection part not working form me. This is my saving controller code.

```
    class CompanyRegistrationController extends BaseController
    {
        public function saveAndCreateCompany()
        {
        // my code which gets form data and saves in database. 
        //After that i am trying to redirect this to another page.
        To acheive this i am trying to do this.
        App::make('AddMoreEmployeeController')->showAddMoreEmployeeDetails();
        }
    }
    // My new page code
    class AddMoreEmployeeController extends BaseController
    {
        public  function showAddMoreEmployeeDetails()
        {
        return View::make('company.addEmployee');
        }
    }
    Routes.php code
        Route::post('/companyCreatedSuccessfully', array('uses' =>     'CompanyRegistrationController@saveAndCreateCompany','as' => 'saveAndCreateCompany'));
        Route::get('/addMoreEmployeeDetails', array('uses' => 'AddMoreEmployeeController@showAddMoreEmployeeDetails','as' => 'showAddMoreEmployeeDetails'));
```

But after filling the form details I am not redirecting to "addMoreEmployeeDetails" .
    I am still in companyCreatedSuccessfully with blank page.But After successful save data in
    database i need to redirect to addMoreEmployeeDetails.
    Where i did mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you only launch other controller but do nothing with its result. You need to return it:

```
return App::make('AddMoreEmployeeController')->showAddMoreEmployeeDetails();
```

and now it will work.

**EDIT**

As you want to change url, it seems you want to make redirection to another controller, so you should use:

```
return Redirect::action('AddMoreEmployeeController@showAddMoreEmployeeDetails');
```

Comment: Yes, i did this , now for me that new page is displaying . But url is not chnaging . It still shows /companyCreatedSuccessfully. But i need /addMoreEmployeeDetails this URL.

Comment: HI Marcin,Please check the below thread ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991021/laravel-4-mail-send-functionality-not-working-properly-with-loop